# How to get table names using sqlite3 through python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, sqlite

I have a problem to get data from the sqlite3 database. I can't find out the names of tables and their encoding. When I open DB through sqlitebrowser names were just unreadable characters.
Connection to DB is fine.

```
conn = sqlite3.connect('my.db')
conn_cursor = conn.cursor()
conn.text_factory = str
```

But how can I get the names of tables and their encoding?

Comment: [The database's text encoding](https://www.sqlite.org/fileformat2.html#enc) is stored as a 4-byte big-endian int at offset 56 in the sqlite database header: `header = open('my.db').read(100); import struct; encoding_type = struct.unpack('>i', header[56:60])[0]`. The `encoding_type` is equal to either 1, 2, or 3 and corresponds to UTF-8, UTF-16LE, or UTF-16BE respectively.

Comment: Opening an SQLite database manually is a good way to get a corrupted database. [Use the `encoding` pragma instead.](http://sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_encoding)

Answer (score 37):

You can use this query to get tables names.

```
res = conn.execute("SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table';")
for name in res.fetchall():
    print(name[0])
```

Comment: Okay. Then to print the value should I call on it `fetchall`? But it returns just an empty list `[]`

Comment: @krzyhub Check my edit.

Comment: Nothing was printed, but it seems that this is for some reason my unaware mistake somewhere else. But thanks.

Comment: @krzyhub For new created db, we need to commit before.