# pandas fail to read sqlite table in spyder

Tags: python, pandas, sqlite, spyder

```
import pandas as pd
import sqlite3
from pandas.io.sql import read_sql


conn = sqlite3.connect('my_database.db3')
data = read_sql('select * from my_table',conn)
```

The issue I am facing here is I can use this code in wing ide to read the table, while Anaconda spyder fails to execute the command:

the output error is :

```
DatabaseError: Execution failed on sql 'select * from my_table': no such table: my_table
```

Any ideas why?

EDIT:

run directly from sqlite3, giving following error:

```
  File "<ipython-input-186-71ea29127489>", line 7, in <module>
    data = conn.execute('select * from my_table;')

OperationalError: no such table: my_table
```

Comment: If you use directly sqlite3, does it work ? If yes, post more info, if no, there it is.

Comment: Try checking if there indeed is `my_table` in your database by listing all table names: `res = conn.execute("SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table';")`. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34570260/how-to-get-table-names-using-sqlite3-through-python) for more info.