# Pandas: Separate column containing semicolon into multiple columns based on the values

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe

My data in ddata.csv is as follows:

```
col1,col2,col3,col4
A,10,a;b;c, 20
B,30,d;a;b,40
C,50,g;h;a,60
```

I want to separate col3 into multiple columns, but based on their values. In other wants, I would like my final data to look like

```
col1, col2, name_a, name_b, name_c, name_d, name_g, name_h, col4
A,    10,   a,      b,      c,      NULL,   NULL,   NULL,   20
B,    30,   a,      b,      NULL,   d,      NULL,   NULL,   40
C,    50,   a,      NULL,   NULL,   NULL,   g,      h,      60
```

My code, at the moment taken reference from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34570260/how-to-get-table-names-using-sqlite3-through-python?noredirect=1&lq=1), is incomplete:

```
import pandas as pd

import string
L = list(string.ascii_lowercase)

names = dict(zip(range(len(L)), ['name_' + x for x in  L]))
df = pd.read_csv('ddata.csv')
df2 = df['col3'].str.split(';', expand=True).rename(columns=names)
```

Column names 'a','b','c' ... are taken at random, and has no relevance to the actual data a,b,c.

Right now, my code can just split 'col3' into three columns as follows:

```
name_a name_b name_c
a      b      c
d      e      f
g      h      i
```

But, it should be like
 name_a, name_b, name_c, name_d, name_g, name_h
 a,      b,      c,      NULL,   NULL,   NULL
 a,      b,      NULL,   d,      NULL,   NULL
 a,      NULL,   NULL,   NULL,   g,      h

and in the end, I need to just replace col3 with these multiple columns.

Comment: @razdi My code just splits column 3 into 3 columns - name_a, name_b, and name_c. But, column name_a  should contain only 'a' and not 'd' or 'h'. I need to segregate the columns based on their values.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.get_dummies`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.get_dummies.html):

```
print (df['col3'].str.get_dummies(';'))
   a  b  c  d  g  h
0  1  1  1  0  0  0
1  1  1  0  1  0  0
2  1  0  0  0  1  1
```

For extract column `col3` from original use [`DataFrame.pop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pop.html), create new `DataFrame` by multiple values by columns names in numpy, replace `NaN`s instead empty strings with [`DataFrame.where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html) and [`DataFrame.add_prefix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.add_prefix.html) for new columns names.

```
pos = df.columns.get_loc('col3')

df2 = df.pop('col3').str.get_dummies(';').astype(bool)
df2 = (pd.DataFrame(df2.values * df2.columns.values[ None, :], 
                    columns=df2.columns,
                    index=df2.index)
         .where(df2)
         .add_prefix('name_'))
```

Last join all DataFrames filtered by positions with `iloc` join together by [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html):

```
df = pd.concat([df.iloc[:, :pos], df2, df.iloc[:, pos:]], axis=1)
print (df)
  col1  col2 name_a name_b name_c name_d name_g name_h  col4
0    A    10      a      b      c    NaN    NaN    NaN    20
1    B    30      a      b    NaN      d    NaN    NaN    40
2    C    50      a    NaN    NaN    NaN      g      h    60
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. How do I now just replace col3 with these multiple columns? without disturbing rest of the columns/rows?

Answer (score 0):

@jezrael solution is excellent. I did not know `str.get_dummies` until now.

I come up with solution using `stack`, `pivot_table`, `np.where` and `pd.concat`

```
df1 = df.col3.str.split(';', expand=True).stack().reset_index(level=0)
df2 = pd.pivot_table(df1, index='level_0', columns=df1[0], aggfunc=len)

Out[1658]:
0          a    b    c    d    g    h
level_0
0        1.0  1.0  1.0  NaN  NaN  NaN
1        1.0  1.0  NaN  1.0  NaN  NaN
2        1.0  NaN  NaN  NaN  1.0  1.0
```

Next, populate `1.0` with column names using `np.where`, find index of `col3` and using `pd.concat` to construct final `df`

```
df2[:] = np.where(df2.isna(), np.nan, df2.columns)
i = df.columns.tolist().index('col3')
pd.concat([df.iloc[:,:i], df2.add_prefix('name_'), df.iloc[:,i+1:]], axis=1)

Out[1667]:
  col1  col2 name_a name_b name_c name_d name_g name_h  col4
0    A    10      a      b      c    NaN    NaN    NaN    20
1    B    30      a      b    NaN      d    NaN    NaN    40
2    C    50      a    NaN    NaN    NaN      g      h    60
```

Comment: I didn't know the str.get_dummies trick either. Jezreal is a genius!